# O/S flushing Chronicle file to disk causing very high latency?

Tags: java, linux, chronicle-queue

We are using *Vanilla Chronicle Queue*, version 3.6.0 in a low-latency application (on Linux Centos machines).

One day, seemingly at random, our client reported a 2.5 second lack of responsiveness in the app (we had been running many months already without this occurring).  We checked *atop* files at the time of the delay, and saw that a process was running the `flush` command at that time.  (Screen shot from *atop* is posted below.)

We are guessing that the O/S flushed the Chronicle memory page to disk, which blocked our processing thread from continuing until the flush was complete.  Another piece of information which points to same conclusion is that internal application stats seem to show the delay occurred right at the point in processing where the thread writes a new entry to the Chronicle.

If this is what happened, we're not sure what caused the Chronicle to flush, since there was a lot of free memory at the time (110G free out of 125G).

So the questions are:

1. Is there a way to know when/if Chronicle gets flushed to disk?
2. What factors would cause such a long flush time?  (This is seems to have happened only once in all these months.)

**ATOP SCREEN SHOT**
[image: Atop screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since we supported queue 3.x but there is some code which causes a flush but it should be only if the user asks for it.
Note: 4.x doesn't yet have this feature but it's an outstanding task to add it.

If any process invokes a sync it can cause all the memory to be flushed on some OSes.

Btw by default only 10% of memory is allowed to be dirty for between 5 and 30 seconds on linux. I suspect there was a burst of activity which left too many pages dirty for too long causing them to all need flushing at once and preventing more pages from being dirtied and the process to pause.

You can increase this limit however I usually suggest in investing in an SSD. You can be mirrored 1 TB for about £1k these days.

Comment: Two follow up questions: 1- Should we be using a different Chronicle version?  (On Maven 3.6.4 seems to be the latest released version).  2- If what happened is that there were too many dirty pages (across all apps), and the flush was unavoidable and SSD would greatly shorten the flush time -- do you have any stats on what difference might be (real or guesstimate)?  Thanks for your response to the question.

Comment: @SamGoldberg The most obvious difference for SSD is the 99%ile is tytpically 1/10.  Generally clients don't sustain high transfer rates and have large memory servers .e.g 0.25 to 0.5 TB main memory so 10% is a burst of at least 25 GB ahead of what is on disk. As a single SATA SSD can sustain about 0.5 GB/s this allows very large bursts.  If you use NVMe, you can write at 1-2 GB/s sustained (until you run out of space)

Comment: @SamGoldberg we don't support 3.x any more, I suggest you try v4. https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.openhft%22%20AND%20a%3A%22chronicle-queue%22 Regular releases are only available to supported clients. I expect we will have another release to maven central at the end of september.